# Is it legal to restrict rental advertisement to local principles only?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, landlord, pennsylvania, advertisements

Being a landlord, I discovered years ago that there are a lot of marketers trying to sell lead lists posing as someone who is relocating. The problem is this, my rentals are in a tiny town that no-one, I mean no-one would likely relocate to unless they are from the area originally. This makes any so-called lead-list pure junk. As well, people entrap landlords into a lawsuits using online advertising. My experience that these forms of drive-bys are also under the guise of a person relocating.

Another issue is that there is a state penitentiary in a neighboring state and the local town is rife with crime as a result. This is because relatives of the inmate want to move closer to the prison. Not being familiar with the area, we often get people trying to move into the area even though the prison is 30-40 miles away. Where people have moved to this area to be near the prison, it has been a disaster resulting in thousands of dollars lost during eviction, damages, and loss in reputation. It is easy to get caught in this trap and I personally lost $8000 last year as a result. Background checks rarely help with this unfortunately.

I only rent to people I can meet, evaluate personally, and can see and approve the rental in person. So far, it has always worked out and I have not had this as a problem until recently when I began advertising on-line. Today I got a on-line lead with no phone number and a throw-away e-mail address that appears to belong to a person in North Carolina doing a search for the e-mail address. There is no other information. For what it is worth, online rental ads are where the marketers and drive-bys get their contacts from. Otherwise, this would not be a problem.

Is my policy legal? As well, it is legal to include in the on-line ad *local residents and principles only*?

**[Edit]** @phoog brings up a great point. Perhaps the policy could be *principles only* and *all inquiries require in-person interviews and approval of the rental*. The policy wording may need to be massaged a bit. Thank You @phoog!

Comment: Probably you mean "principals", since local principles would be a case of situational ethics :-)  But as far as legality goes (IANAL) you should be good since you don't specify any of the impermissible restrictions (sex,age, religion, marital status, etc)

Comment: @MMacD I know my wording is not the best on this. I do actually want to restrict responses from people who are not from the area unless they are from the area originally. We do get people coming home and that is fine. Otherwise, people who are not from here really have no reason to come here short of retirees. And even then, this is a predominately Mennonite farming region and a bit rough if you are not used to living in the country. The people are absolutely lovely, it is just the area is culturally stern and not necessarily user friendly.

Comment: @MMacD To give you some context, a friend of mine from Pennsylvania, raised on a farm near the Amish (Amish are Old Order Mennonites), just two hours east of us, had a hard time getting along because the Mennonites and other locals cast a hard eye on people from out of the area. If you are a traveler, they will welcome you into their home, insist upon it, feed you, and treat you extremely well, however, if you move in next door, then you better be local culturally or you will not fit in. My friend moved back home after just a couple of years of being frustrated. Sad really.

Comment: Interesting question. It seems to me that discriminating based on current or previous place of residence ought to be prohibited, but doesn't seem to be prohibited explicitly by the FHA. Of course, it could be prohibited by judicial interpretation or by another law. If it *is* prohibited, you might be able to achieve your goal by other means. For example, requiring a personal interview seems like it should be legal, and there may be other (more directly relevant) criteria you can use to meet your entirely reasonable and legal goals of avoiding destructive or deadbeat tenants.

Comment: @phoog *requiring a personal interview* Your comment appeared just as I was thinking of the same thing. I could easily modify the policy requiring a personal viewing of the apartment and a personal meeting. I personally do not care if someone is relocating, it is just that after so many years, it is beyond rare for this area that it works out okay. The local landlords are few here and we know each other and talk. We all share the same experiences. Cheers!!

Comment: @phoog The policy could also help solve other problems. People will sometimes shop for an apartment for another. This is almost always for a bad reason; bad credit, criminal history, currently selling drugs, generally irresponsible and being kicked out of the house, or even elder dumping. You would be surprised how many of my requests are for these reasons. I expect the application and lease to solve these problems, however, posting a reasonable policy may help keep the noise down. I run a very nice house and is one of the reasons why I do this - affordable quality living for good people.

Comment: Everything before "I only rent to people I can meet, ..." is irrelevant to the end question in a general sense, and makes the question seem very much a request for personal legal advice on your specific policy and reasoning. Does it actually have to be there?

Comment: @Nij It has been my working policy to restrict access to those I have met and view the apartment even if not actually stated. Landlords are often sued by drive-bys as a result of an ad. This is extremely common. I have this question on AVVO and will potentially put it to my attorney. I just thought it was an interesting question for AVVO and SE users as a thought exercise. It is nearly impossible to ask a question here without a solicitation for legal advice. I am not accepting any answers as legal advice, but rather as a good solid answer. You are making a good and valid point! Cheers!!

Comment: @Nij If you are referring to the edit, I thought it was a good point within the comments that should live and not disappear.

Comment: What I mean is, the reasons you have for this policy are largely irrelevant to the question: *I have this policy, here's what it does, is that allowed*. If you took out all of the first two paragraphs completely and didn't change anything from "I only rent ..." through to "... and principals only?", the question would still be complete, would still have largely the same answer, and would still be useful and interesting. I'm not worried about the edit, if it clarifies something inside the section I suggest keeping, perhaps it could also be more properly integrated onto that section too.

Comment: @Nij Okay. I get it! Yes. You are right. However, when you are talking about things that people can perceive as discrimination, the Why? of it all often helps to understand the goal. I want to not only keep the noise down, but stop the drive-bys, and stop the inquiries that are not within a reasonable scope. For example, it is not advisable to either buy or sell a car that the purchaser has not seen, test driven, etc. And since this is my house (as defined within law) any guest (also defined by law) should be someone I am at least familiar and comfortable with. Renting is extremely tricky.

Comment: @Nij Tricky especially in light of the drive-bys who like to sue people who they have never met or spoken to for discrimination or perceived discrimination. It takes $20,000 just to get to court before you can present any evidence on a complaint. I know. I have been sued by a drive-by. It was a painful 3 years of my life I will never get back, extremely expensive, and placed a stain on my professional reputation that was never deserved. The Why? is very important I felt. It is not without consequences. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc:  Apropos people moving away again, the same thing happens in Minnesota, where the culture is Scandinavian and Germanic rather than Mediterranean.  People move out from the East Coast for work and then move back in a year or so, complaining that Minnesotans are cold, unwelcoming, two-faced, and passive-aggressive.  Which isn't true at all. Incomers from Scandinavia or Germany fit in seamlessly:  they know that nobody will hand-hold them, but, if disaster strikes, people whose names they barely know will come out of the woodwork with real help and comfort.  And then disappear again!

Comment: @MMacD And I thought it was just us! Cheers!! Another local issue is that there is very little work, it is manual labor mostly, very particular to the culture such as factory work, farming, logging, mining, etc. So really, almost no-one is moving because of a job. ;-) There is some exception of course. I do help people who move into the area. It is just right since I am foreign to this area too (though I have been here for a very long time). However, some city mice do not listen and offend the country mice who then shun them. Oh well. Cannot win 'em all.